# USB Drive Not Showing Up

Tags: 22.04, usb-drive

I just bought a new Lexar 128GB thumb drive. My system was using it at first and allowing me to transfer data to it. All of a sudden while using it, it stopped working. I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Is there any way of correcting this? Without replacing? I have tried on other systems as well to achieve this to include Windows versions 8-11 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Replace the drive?

Comment: how is the thumb drive formatted ?  ext3, fat32, vfat for example.  Did your system ever go to sleep while copying a lot of files ?

Comment: @mondotofu it is fat32, computer had not fallen asleep while copying files, it just as it was copying approx. 32G data onto a 128G drive stopped recognizing the device.

Comment: @Pilot6 I would like to be able to at least retrieve the data that I had put on it. Are their any forensic tools that could help recognize it at least long enough for me to retrieve the data from it

Comment: Plug the drive into a computer running Windows and run `chkdsk Z:" where Z is the USB drive.

Comment: @user68186 That would requie the computer to be recognizing the device. is there a way of putting a variable there to have it look for additional drives?

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution. -- There are problems if no computer can see the USB drive as a 'mass storage device', but if you are lucky there is 'only confusion'.

Comment: There are as many as 1/3 of USB drives on the market today that are counterfeit. And some are certified for a given capacity, but scammers will paste their own labels advertising twice the capacity and sell them at a bargain price to move them. So beware.