# USB not detected on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb

I have a Kingston 32 GB USB that does not show up on my laptop. I can't see it on the disks utility so I'm guessing it's not a mounting issue. Here is the output of `lsblk`

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
zram0           251:0    0   7.5G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme0n1         259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0  1022M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0     4G  0 part  /recovery
├─nvme0n1p3     259:3    0 229.5G  0 part  
│ └─cryptdata   252:0    0 229.5G  0 crypt 
│   └─data-root 252:1    0 229.5G  0 lvm   /
└─nvme0n1p4     259:4    0     4G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap   252:2    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

Here is the output for `sudo dmesg | grep -i usb`

```
[76481.543758] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 1.10
[76481.543775] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[76481.543782] usb 2-1: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[76481.543788] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[76481.543793] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: E0D55EA574C61681E94C19F6
[76481.559394] failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
[76481.602302] failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
```

What can I do to fix this?

More info: The USB was working fine until a week ago, I used it on a friend's laptop that has Windows on it and I'm wondering if that created the problem? If yes, Some explanation would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: there are some comments in response to [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435624/usb-drive-not-showing-up) worth looking at

Comment: thanks for pointing to that, the only comment relevant to my situation is the one about putting it back into windows and diagnosing the issue. I don't have easy access to a windows computer so I'd prefer a ubuntu based solution, if possible

Comment: did you read right through the comments under the linked post? There was a [further reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435624/usb-drive-not-showing-up) which was Linux specific

Comment: If the USB stick was unplugged from your friend's computer without proper 'safe removal' or left while Windows was shut down, the file system might be 'dirty'. In that case going back to your friend, plugging it in and ''safe removal' while Windows is still running might help. But if you have bad luck, the hardware of the USB drive has been damaged. -- You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: @graham I assume you mean the link in comment 7 there. I did check that and my situation is one where device is not detected. I still can't see the device with the suggestions there.

Comment: @sudodus I just tried putting it into a friends windows computer, it does show up with all contents, I did an eject safely and I still can't see it on ubuntu. I even tried formatting it (exFAT and FAT32 both) by right clicking on the windows machine and that doesn't work either. The fact that it shows up there tells me the the hardware is okay. Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Comment: You could test according this: Make an Ubuntu live drive (in another USB pendrive) and when booted into the live system try to read from and write to the problematic USB pendrive in the same computer and in another computer. This means testing different operating systems in the same computer and testing the same (live) operating system in two different computers, how they can manage the problematic USB pendrive. Please remember that you should write some file to the drive and after safe un-plugging and re-plugging check that the written file is really there. A pendrive might 'pretend' to work.